# Do I need a BindingSource AND a BindingList for WinForms DataBinding?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource, bindinglist

I want to display a list of people in a `DataGridView` in a Windows Forms app.  I want my service layer to return a list of Person objects (e.g., `IList<Person>`).  I want changes in the list to be reflected in the `DataGridView` and vice versa.  My understanding is that using the `BindingSource` facilitates working with `DataGridView`.  My question is for the two-way databinding to work, do I need:

```
//pseudo code
BindingSource.DataSource = IBindingList<Person>
```

or can I do:

```
BindingSource.DataSource = IList<Person>
```

What's the difference?  If my make changes to the list will the `DataGridView` be updated either way?  And if I have to use the `BindingList`, it seems a little wonky (because of creating a dependency) to return a `BindingList` from my service layer, is there a way around that?

Microsoft says of the `BindingList` (in the Remarks section)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx:

> "However, the typical solutions
>   programmer will use a class that
>   provides data binding functionality,
>   such as `BindingSource`, instead of
>   directly using `BindingList<T>`."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `BindingList<T>` then changes that you make through the underlying list will be reflected in the data bound controls because BindingList raises an event when the list is changed. Most other collections do not.

If you use a normal collection as the data source then changes that you make through other data bound controls (or through the BindingSource) will still be reflected, but changes to the underlying collection directly will not.

Comment: Part of my confusion was that some people seemed to suggest you did not need to use a BindingList to get two-way databinding as long as you were using a BindingSource.  But I guess what you're saying is that's only true if you only modify the list through the BindingSource.

Answer (score 12):

Binding to an `IList<Person>` will only give you one-way binding; changes to the list or list items will not be reflected in the `DataGridView`. You can use a `BindingList` or `BindingSource` to get this functionality instead, but your `Person` class will still need to support `INotifyPropertyChanged` or else you will only get synchronisation when items are added/removed to/from the list, not when the list items themselves change.

If you want to avoid a dependency on `System.Windows.Forms`, you could use `ObservableCollection<Person>` instead; this supports the necessary change notifications and can therefore be used as a two-way binding source.

Comment: Unless he's using .NET 4, ObservableCollection carries an even more burdensome dependency because it is defined in a WPF assembly (WindowsBase). It was only moved to System.dll in .NET 4.

Comment: What's the difference between BindingList<T> and BindingSource? I tried both and both seem to work. Is one newer than the other? Should one prefer BindingList<T> because it is typed?

Comment: @Lernkurve The main difference is that `BindingSource` is a WinForms component whereas `BindingList<T>` can be used in any type of application. `BindingSource` has a few extra display/presentation features that improve the user experience in WinForms.