# DataGridView returns rows without data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a an issue in my windows application project, a very small one I'm afraid which for some reason I can't get a hang of the solution.

I want to display data in a Data grid programmatically, but it returns only the rows based on the number of records fetched from the database **WITHOUT** Data in it. Below is my code

```
private void BindDataToGrid()
{
    var teller = new TellerService().GetByUsername(username);
    var transactions = new PocTransactionService().GetByTellerId(teller.TellerId);
    BindingList<PocTransaction> trans = new BindingList<PocTransaction>(transactions);
    var source = new BindingSource(trans, null);
    dgvTransactions.DataSource = source;
}
```

Not that the variable `transactions` gets populated in the code, but for some reason, it's not displaying on grid. It's really driving me nuts. I trust one of you here to show me the way out.

Comment: why not `var source = new BindingSource(trans);`?

Comment: `BindingSource` doesn't take less than two arguments Gabriel. But thanks for your response.

Comment: Second parameter (`DataMember`) default value is `""`. Maybe that will help.. When working with `BindingSource`, I usually use the default constructor, then set the `DataSource`.

Comment: Still didn't work Gabriel. Can you share the code you use to make it work?

Comment: Ohh.. and I didn't see before, but you're using `BindingList` AND `BindingSource`.. try binding the BindingList directly : `dgvTransactions.DataSource = trans;`.

Comment: You might also want to read this : [do i need a bindingsource and a bindinglist for winforms databinding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675874/do-i-need-a-bindingsource-and-a-bindinglist-for-winforms-databinding)

Comment: That didn't solve my problem either. It just keeps returning empty rows and no data within it.

Comment: can you see data in your `var transactions` in debug mode?

Comment: Yes I do. When I put mouse over it, I see "Count = 10"

Comment: Do you use `dgvTransactions.AutoGenerateColumn = true;` or do you define your columns? Are you using properties in your `PocTransaction`  class (public variables arn't recognized in databinding)? ...

Comment: I set the `AutoGenerateColumn` property to `false` in the page_Load. But I defined my columns using the smart tag of the datagridview control. Could this be the problem? And yes my `PocTransaction` class is using properties. I use Nettiers so it automatically generates my classes and Business Objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. There is nothing wrong with the code I wrote in the first place. I just didn't set the `DataPropertyName` for each of the columns I defined on the grid. Setting them appropriately to the datasource property gave my the desired result.

All  thanks to Gabriel for his help so far. I appreciate.