# DataGridView bound to List does not reflect changes when adding objects to the List

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I wonder what I need to do in order to make the DataGridView behave as expected:

I do have a `List<ioChannel>` (named ***myList***) of objects of this type:

```
public class ioChannel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to bind the DataGridView to this list:

```
bs = new BindingSource { DataSource = myList };
dgvChannels.DataSource = bs;
```

Now I created a button that adds elements to ***myList***:

```
private void btAddChannel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myList.Add(new ioChannel() { Id = myList.Count, Name = "My Channel" });
}
```

When I press the button, my List gets populated with new `ioChannel`'s, but the `dgvChannels` does not add any rows. What do I need to do in order to make this happen?

BTW: When `myList` gets populated with some `ioChannel`´s before assigning the BindingSource as DataSource, the get shown properly in the grid.

Comment: I think you need to use a `BindingList<T>`. It has events that the DGV can listen to.

Answer (score 5):

As @Loathing commented **BindingList** worked for me too. How it will work :

```
BindingList<ioChannel> myList = new BindingList<ioChannel>();
dgvChannels.DataSource = myList;
```

BindingList has event that notifies changes in list. So that datagridview can notified to redraw itself, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675874/do-i-need-a-bindingsource-and-a-bindinglist-for-winforms-databinding). For more information visit [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).