# Data doesn't show at the datagrid when added in the list bounded to an object DataSouce

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list of person that is bounded with the dataGridView, but when I add new data and store to the list, it doesn't show that it is added in the dataGridView.

The code shows like this

```
private IList<Person> personList = new List<Person>();

private void AddPerson()
    {

        var count = personList.Count;
        var finId = 0;
        if (count != 0)
        {
            var valid = personList.LastOrDefault();
            if (valid != null)
            {
                finId = valid.Id;
            }
        }

        var person = new Person
        {
            Id = ++finId,
            FirstName = tbFirstName.Text,
            LastName = tbFirstName.Text,
            Email = tbEmail.Text,
            DateOfBirth = dtDateOfBirth.Value
        };

        personList.Add(person);
    }

private void PopulateGrid()
    {
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = personList;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new Person
        {
            Id = 1,
            FirstName = "Randolf",
            LastName = "Segubre",
            Email = "rsegubre@gmail.com",
            DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse("08/28/1991"),
        });
        personBindingSource.DataSource = personList;
    }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopulateGrid();
    }

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddPerson();
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Added","INFORMATION",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        this.Clear();

    }
```

The default values where displayed at the dataGridView but when you add data while the program is running, it doesn't show it the dataGridView.
But it shows its been added in the `personList`. Just doesn't add in the dataGridView

Comment: Using a BindingList instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView bound to List does not reflect changes when adding objects to the List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832164/datagridview-bound-to-list-does-not-reflect-changes-when-adding-objects-to-the-l).  I found this in less than a second using your own title in a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to all the comments and answer I've got, thank you guys. I found what I need. Here is my answer.

```
private IList<Person> _personList = new List<Person>();

private void PopulateGrid()
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = _personList;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
    }

private void AddPerson()
    {
        var count = _personList.Count;
        var finId = 0;
        if (count != 0)
        {
            var valid = _personList.LastOrDefault();
            if (valid != null)
            {
                finId = valid.Id;
            } 
        }

        var person = new Person
        {
            Id = ++finId,
            FirstName = tbFirstName.Text,
            LastName = tbFirstName.Text,
            Email = tbEmail.Text,
            DateOfBirth = dtDateOfBirth.Value
        };
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Added", "INFORMATION", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        _personList.Add(person);
        this.PopulateGrid();
    }
```

I didn't change the IList to BindingList. It stay the same but I added the a BindingSource.

I added the list to the bindingsource's DataSource before putting it to the the datagridview's DataSource. Then Call it to the AddPerson method so that every time the AddPerson is executed, the datagridview will also be reloaded.