# Binding List continues to track changes

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, 2-way-object-databinding

On the form (in the constructor) I have a DataGridView control and a BindingSource. As DataSource for the BindingSource selected my Order class. For DataGridView - BindingSource. I load data like this:

```
context.Orders.Load();
orderBS.DataSource = context.Orders.Local.ToBindingList();
```

All is working well. I edit data in a separate form and pass it an instance of the Order class (orderBS.Current as Order). In this form I save the changes - context.SaveChanges(). Go back and DataGridView is updated. Now I want to make search field. When you click on the button "Search" I'm doing the following:

```
bindingSource.DataSource = context.Orders.Where(x => x.Contains(txtBox.Value)).ToList();
```

Now it turns out orderBS tied just to the List. The data is normally filtered. Just as I give the Order instance. Open the form and edit - the DataGridView is updated!!! Why? I do not call ToBindingList().

I found discussion of this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675874/do-i-need-a-bindingsource-and-a-bindinglist-for-winforms-databinding). Bradley Smith responded thus:

> You can use a BindingList or BindingSource to get this functionality
>   instead, but your Person class will still need to support
>   INotifyPropertyChanged or else you will only get synchronisation when
>   items are added/removed to/from the list, not when the list items
>   themselves change.

But my Order class is very simple and does not support INotifyPropertyChanged. Why DataGridView is updated?

Comment: The problem is that I filtered the data and then call the method ToList(). When I edit data in the DataGridView is still updated?! I can't understand why! I'm not tied to the data through ToBindingList().

Comment: Really nobody knows the answer to this question. Maybe the question is not clear?